# date_add for timestamp in Hive

Tags: hive, presto, trino

im currently running a query in presto db which has a condition like below:

`x.created_date > date_add('day',-15,y.arrival_timestamp )`

I plan to move the query to hive and want to know what is the  alternative to get the comparision to work exactly as above, when i run the query in Hive

Created_date sample value
`2020-12-04T15:47:15.497000`

arrival_timestamp sample value
`2020-11-24T21:08:20.046000`

Any help would be appreciated.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `date_sub` in Hive:

```
x.created_date > date_sub(y.arrival_timestamp, 15)
```